# Unable to create a new folder in Azure file share by a Windows service running in Azure VM

Tags: azure, windows-services, azure-file-share

Have a Windows service running in a Azure Windows Server 2022 VM, also mapped the Azure file share to a Windows drive Z:\ in this VM according to [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-quick-create-use-windows), the Windows service is trying to create a folder *ABC* in the Z:\test folder, but it didn't work, how to fix this?

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("Z:\\test\\ABC");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have storage account with one file share named **`srifileshare`** like below:

[image]

In that file share, I added one **directory** named **`test`** like below:

[image]

To map **file share** to Windows VM, I got Powershell script from here:

[image]

When I ran the above script in my Windows VM, it mapped to **file share** successfully like below:

[image]

When I checked the same in File Explorer, **Z drive** is available with **`test`** folder in it like below:

[image]

When I tried to create `ABC` folder inside **`test`** folder, it created successfully like below:

[image]

I checked the same in Portal where `ABC` directory is created in **file share** successfully like below:

[image]

> Note that, only **UNC paths** are supported to create a directory on a remote computer or on a share

In your case, try changing the **path** from `Z:\\test\\ABC` to below:

```cs
Directory.CreateDirectory("\\\\<storageaccountname>.file.core.windows.net\\<storagefilesharename>\\test\\ABC");
```

**Reference:**

[Directory.CreateDirectory Method (System.IO) Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=net-7.0#system-io-directory-createdirectory(system-string))

Comment: Thanks @Sridevi, it works now after changing the path to network format path :)